# how to fill the missing date info

Tags: r, function, date

I am try to build a function for missing date imputation. The sample data set is

```
StartDate <-c("UN Mar 2011","UN UNK 2013","UN UNK 2013","UN Jul 2014","UN UNK 2013","UN May 2018","UN UNK 2013","UN UNK 2013","UN May 2010","UN UNK 2014","UN UNK 2007","UN Dec 2017","UN Apr 2017","UN UNK 2008","UN Nov 2017")

EndDate <- c( "UN Mar 2011","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","un May 2010","UN Jan 2017","un UNK 2007","NA","UN Jul 2017","NA","UN Nov 2017")

Sample.data <- data.frame(StartDate, EndDate)
```

I would like to define the function to impute the date following following rule:

• Day is missing then day is set to the first day of the month;
• Day is missing and month is missing then date will be set to 01 January;
• Complete date is missing then will be set to missing.

Comment: In the data you created, the missing values are quoted.

Comment: In the example, it is the year and month, showed.  Can you show the expected output

Comment: Hello, I have updated my question with the results that I want to get and the codes that I wrote so far. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should meet your requirements.

It uses the regular expression `"^.*?(\\d{4}).*?$"` which will capture any four-digit year and return it. If there is no four-digit year it will return the whole string. When we attempt to convert that to numeric, we will therefore get either a year or an `NA`.

We then split the strings on spaces and search for any month abbreviations in the second element. If there are none there, we substitute a 1. We do the same for the first component, searching for numbers 1:31.

Finally, we paste year, month and day together and attempt to convert to a date. If we don't have a year we will get an `NA`. If there was a year but no month, the month is `1`, and if there was no day, it becomes a 1 also.

```
impute_dates <- function(x)
{
  years  <- gsub("^.*?(\\d{4}).*?$", "\\1", x)
  years  <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(years))
  months <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 2), month.abb)
  months[is.na(months)] <- 1
  days <- match(sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " "), `[`, 1), 1:31)
  days[is.na(days)] <- 1
  data.frame(years, months, days)
  as.Date(paste(years, months, days, sep = "-"))
}
```

So you can do:

```
impute_dates(Sample.data$StartDate)
#>  [1] "2011-03-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2014-07-01" "2013-01-01"
#>  [6] "2018-05-01" "2013-01-01" "2013-01-01" "2010-05-01" "2014-01-01"
#> [11] "2007-01-01" "2017-12-01" "2017-04-01" "2008-01-01" "2017-11-01"


impute_dates(Sample.data$EndDate)
#>  [1] "2011-03-01" NA           NA           NA           NA          
#>  [6] NA           NA           NA           "2010-05-01" "2017-01-01"
#> [11] "2007-01-01" NA           "2017-07-01" NA           "2017-11-01"
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried and it works. I am new to R and have some difficulty understand regular expression. Is it OK to explain  it a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much. That is a very smart way. :)

Comment: we used ```sapply(strsplit(as.character(x), " ")``` to split variables into 3 pieces. For date and month, for both used ``` `[`, 2), ```. Does that mean tha t we only check the second chunk of the variable. I am a little confused. Did I read it wrong?

Comment: What will happen if we have sth looks like "un YYYY"? Then the second part will be year info.

Comment: @Stataq you are right - this is a mistake. I will change it. Well spotted!

Comment: @Stataq as long as the second part doesn't match a month name that would be OK, and the year is picked up separately. You need to tweak text parsing depending on the possible inputs. My solution will work with inputs like those you show, but if you have different inputs then of course the code will need expanded to accommodate these.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty simple tidyverse approach. This is probably less robust and assumes the missing day and month are actually coded as "UN" and "UNK".

Requires a couple packages, but fairly readable.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

impute_dates <- function(x) {
  dmy(str_replace(str_replace(toupper(x), "UN", "1"), "UNK", "Jan"), quiet = TRUE)
}
```